# Issue for insert using psycopg

Tags: python, postgresql, matlab, psycopg2, pytables

I am reading data from a .mat file using the Pytables module. After reading the data, I want to insert this data into the database using psycopg.
Here is a sample code piece:

```
file = tables.openFile(matFile)
x = 0
#populate the matData list
for var in dest:
   data = file.getNode('/' + var)[:]
   matData.append(data) 
   x = x+1 
#insert into db
for i in range(0,x):
   cur.execute("""INSERT INTO \"%s\" (%s) VALUES (%s)""" % tableName,dest[i],matData[i]) )
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./loadDBFromMAT.py", line 111, in <module>
    readInputFileAndLoad(args.matFileName,args.tableName)
  File "./loadDBFromMAT.py", line 77, in readInputFileAndLoad
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO \"%s\" (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (tableName,dest[i],matData[i]) )
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "DUMMY1km" (data) VALUES ([[-3000 -3000 -3000 .....
```

It would be great if anyone can suggest a workaround for this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `INSERT` statement has invalid syntax. There something wrong inside the for loop you mention.
<sub>You should include the for loop in the question.</sub>

> INSERT INTO "DUMMY1km" (data) VALUES ([[-3000 -3000 -3000 .....

A valid statement could look like this - assuming your column is of type `integer[]`.
<sub>... which you should also include in the question.</sub>

```
INSERT INTO "DUMMY1km"(data) VALUES ('{-3000, -3000}'::int[])
```

or

```
INSERT INTO "DUMMY1km"(data) VALUES (ARRAY[-3000, -3000])  -- note the "ARRAY"
```

or for a 2-dimensional array (looks a bit like that in the error msg.):

```
INSERT INTO "DUMMY1km"(data) VALUES ('{{-3000, -3000}, {-3000, -3000}}'::int[])
```

or

```
INSERT INTO "DUMMY1km"(data) VALUES (ARRAY[[-3000, -3000],[-3000, -3000]])
```

More on [array value input](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) in the manual.

#### Ergo:

matData[i] needs to contain `ARRAY[-3000, -3000]` or one of the other listed variants of valid syntax instead of `[[-3000 -3000 -3000 ...` which isn't valid for an integer array.

Psychopg automatically converts a **PostgreSQL array** into a **Python list**. When building the INSERT, you need to convert the list back to an array. I quote from [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation):

> ```
> Python lists are converted into PostgreSQL ARRAYs:
>
> >>> cur.mogrify("SELECT %s;", ([10, 20, 30], ))
> 'SELECT ARRAY[10, 20, 30];'
> ```

<sub>Disclaimer: I am an expert with PostgreSQL, not so much with Python. For somebody who knows Python better than me, it should be easy to format the string accordingly. I found the above quote in a quick research on the web.</sub>

Comment: I have added the for loop in the code. Basically the 
INSERT statement is getting the value from the matData[i] variable.(the [[3000... is the value of which is shown in the error message) The matData list is populated by reading the .mat file using pyTables.

Comment: @Aditya: What is the datatype of "DUMMY1km".data?

Comment: @Aditya; Then I guess right, and my answer should help you already. I'll edit with an emphasis on `matData[i]`.

Comment: Yeah, but the issue is in formatting the array returned by pyTables to be suited for the insert. I am still looking into how to remove that extra '[' from the array and insert ',' between the values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4096/discussion-between-aditya-and-erwin-brandstetter)