# Insert python list into Postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am having trouble in formatting the list for insertion using psycopg.
Here is a sample of code i am trying to do.
Basically I am just reading data from one table and trying to insert it into another table.

Code:

```
cur.execute("""select data from \"Table1\" where lat=-20.004189 and lon=-63.848004""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
print rows
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO \"%s\" (data) VALUES (ARRAY%s)""" % (args.tableName,rows)))
```

The result returned by first select query is like this:

```
[([6193, 3975, 4960, 5286, 3380, 970, 3328, 3173, 2897, 2457, 2443, 2674, 2172, 2740, 3738, 4907, 3691, 4234, 3651, 3215],)]
```

When I try to insert this into another table I get the following format error.

```
   cur.execute(cur.mogrify("""INSERT INTO \"%s\" (data) VALUES (%s)""" % (args.tableName,rows)))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "DUMMY1km" (data) VALUES ([([6193, 3975, 4960, 5...
```

I tried cur.mogrify, but it does not seem to help.

Please let me know if anyone has a work around for this issue.

Thanks
Adi

Comment: Column data is an **array**, the syntax for the value is invalid as already diagnosed [in this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681622/issue-for-insert-using-psycopg). Where I could not help: better python syntax to create valid syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying out different ways of sending the array as a parameter. This was just one of the attempts.! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `mogrify` is needed here. Use `executemany` and pass `rows` as the second argument.

```
cur.executemany(
    """INSERT INTO "%s" (data) VALUES (%%s)""" % (args.tableName),rows)
```

Using parametrized arguments helps prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

The table name can not be parametrized, so we do have to use string interpolation to place the table name in the SQL query. `%%s` gets escapes the percent sign and becomes `%s` after string interpolation.

---

By the way, (as [a_horse_with_no_name has already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760052/insert-python-list-into-postgres-database/7760247#7760247)) you can use the [INSERT INTO ... SELECT form](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html) of `INSERT` to perform both SQL queries as one:

```
cur.execute(
    """INSERT INTO %s (data)
       SELECT data FROM Table1
       WHERE lat=-20.004189 AND lon=-63.848004""" % (args.tableName))
```

---

Per the question in the comments, if there are multiple fields, then the SQL becomes:

```
cur.executemany(
    """INSERT INTO {t} (lat,lon,data1,data2) 
       VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""".format(t=args.tableName),rows)
```

(If you use the `format` method, then you don't have to escape all the other `%s`s.)

Comment: If I try execute many, it get the this as error:TypeError: Required argument 'vars_list' (pos 2) not found 
Also, I intend to read data from a file before inserting. So cannot always combine insert and select

Comment: Please post the exact `cur.executemany` statement. And what is `vars_list`?

Comment: `cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO \"%s\" (data) VALUES (%s)""" % (args.tableName,rows))` `vars_list` was included in the TypeError thrown by python

Comment: Move the `rows` outside the parentheses. (See how I wrote it in my post above).

Comment: What is there are multiple attributes in row. Right now there is only data. But is there is lat,lon,data1, data2 then how should we use the executemany function?