# Syntax to call a PostgreSQL function that contains an array among its arguments

Tags: arrays, function, postgresql, testing

I am testing some PostgreSQL functions that I did not write, one of which is defined like:

```
email_maker_for_new_work_order(integer, character varying, integer[]);
```

I'm trying to call it like:

```
select email_maker_for_new_work_order(13987,"TEST_CeeLoGreen",['231822','267657','268399','270125','270127','270470','271320'])
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ..._maker_for_new_work_order(13987,"TEST_CeeLoGreen",['231822',...
                                                             ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
SQL state: 42601
Character: 63
```

I've tried without the single-quotes around the integer array. However, I get essentially the same error at the same location.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have compiled a list of valid syntax variants for integer arrays recently in an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681622/issue-for-insert-using-psycopg/7681837#7681837

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The syntax is

```
array[1,2,3]
```

and note, that the arguments are not strings as in  `'42'` but plain integers like `42`.

By the way: The part `"TEST_CeeLoGreen"` is interpreted as a column name, not as a plain string. Is that intended?

Comment: So you mean: select email_maker_for_new_work_order(13987,'TEST_CeeLoGreen',array[231822,267657,268399,270125,270127,270470,271320])

Comment: Yes. Because there is no table the `TEST...` thing _must_ be a string.